# Problem using object as output path for arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_Management

Tags: arcpy

I am simply trying to create a selection of a street layer from street names that appear within a separate .dbf of street names and create individual layers of each selection with a for loop. Everything works until the last step where I use the object to serve as the path string for the resulting layer.

Is this not allowed in arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management? I have looked everywhere for the answer. I have also tried both \ and / within the pathname and with/without an "r" in front of the pathname. Here is the latest version of the code:

```
import arcpy
import sys, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'Test.gdb')
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("COR_Length_Sum_Greater_Half_Mile")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("COR_Maintained", "CORlyr")
for row in rows:
    street = row.getValue("Display_Street")
    expression = "Display_Street" + " " + "=" + " " + '\'' + str(street) + '\''
    lyrName = street.replace(" ", "_")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("COR_Maintained", lyrName, expression)
    outLayer = "r" + '\"' + "A:\\" + "StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati" + "\\" + lyrName + '\"'
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyrName, outLayer)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is just that you've got a funny path going on.  When I printed it, it looks like this `r"A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati\lyrname"` which at first seems good.  However, the "r" should not show up in the printed path, and neither should the "", it should simply print as `A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati\lyrname`.  Also it's a layer file so I believe you need to add ".lyr" to the end of the path.

Here are two great ways to make paths:

1. `os.path.join()`: just pass each path component as an argument and the a string with the correct separators will be created.  For example

`os.path.join("A:\\StreetMaintenance","GIS","Justin Castrati",lyrName+".lyr")`

2. using `str.format()`: create the shell of a path and use the format method to pass variables into it.  For example (note the use of 'r' *outside* of the quotes)

`r"A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati\{0}.lyr".format(lyrName)`

I also prefer making an `outdir` variable that can hold the target directory location, just so I only ever have to write that path one time in the whole script.  For example

```
outDir = r"A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati"
outLayer = r"{0}\{1}.lyr".format(outDir,lyrName)
```

A really good way to test this stuff out is IDLE, just open it up and trying printing your path variables to make sure they are constructed correctly.

Comment: That worked! I think that the main issue is I was trying to put in the " for the argument when i didn't need to. That wasn't the smartest mistake I have made... :/ but thanks a ton for the help!!

Comment: I am new to python so help from patient people like you guys (mr. adam and Emil Brundage) is awesome! Thank you both :)

Comment: Sure.  The second method I used is really my favorite way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The `'\"'` at the start and end of your code is one issue. Get rid of those. Also, add an r at the start of any string paths with single backslash.

Just to get your feet wet, I'd suggest starting with a path you know exists and building from there. Copy/paste a folder path from ArcCatalog or Windows explorer, and add a layer file at the end of it. Something like:

```
r"C:\Test\Test.lyr"
```

Make sure that works first. Yours would probably be this:

```
outLayer = r"A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati" + "\\" + lyrName + ".lyr"
```

Or better:

```
import os

outLayer = os.path.join (r"A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati", lyrName + ".lyr")
```

Comment: As of now, the object outLayer prints out as: r"A:\StreetMaintenance\GIS\Justin Castrati\ACC_BV" When i put that string in the output instead of the outLayer object it works fine. Without the ' \" ' in the begining I do not get the " to start the argument. I am sure there is much better syntax to get the result that I want (I am obviously new to python), but the string this produces seems right... No?

Comment: See my edits...